# Is there a way to get keys from a map based on a column condition using spark dataframe?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have the following dataframe:

```scala
val df = Seq(
    (Map("a" -> "1", "b" -> "2", "c" -> "3"), Seq("a","b"))
    ).toDF("internalMap","commonList")
```

```scala
df.show()

+------------------------+----------+
|internalMap             |commonList|
+------------------------+----------+
|[a -> 1, b -> 2, c -> 3]|[a, b]    |
+------------------------+----------+
```

How can I get interalMap values, where the array of keys equals array of valueList ?

I have tried to use:

```scala
val getMapElements = df.select(map_keys(col("internalMap")).as("internalMapKeys"), map_values(col("internalMap")).as("internalMapValues"))
    
getMapElements.show()

+---------------+-----------------+
|internalMapKeys|internalMapValues|
+---------------+-----------------+
|      [a, b, c]|        [1, 2, 3]|
+---------------+-----------------+

    
getMapElements.select("internalMapValues").where(col("commonList") isin col("internalMapKeys")).show()

+-----------------+
|internalMapValues|
+-----------------+
+-----------------+
```

But it returns an empty array. What is expected is:

```scala
+-----------------+
|internalMapValues|
+-----------------+
|           [1, 2]|
+-----------------+
```

The most difficult thing, is that only spark dataframe functions are accepted in my use case.

Thank you in advance for your help

Comment: Spark version ??

Comment: Spark version is: 2.4+

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `expr`, `transform` functions to get expected result. Check below code.

```
scala> df
.withColumn(
    "internalMapValues",
    expr("transform(commonList,v -> internalMap[v])") // Pass commonList value to map as key.
)
.show(false)
```

```
+------------------------+----------+-----------------+
|internalMap             |commonList|internalMapValues|
+------------------------+----------+-----------------+
|[a -> 1, b -> 2, c -> 3]|[a, b]    |[1, 2]           |
+------------------------+----------+-----------------+
```